# How can I make this campaign less NPC oriented?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, npc, new-gm

I'm the GM this time, playing D&D 5e, I have planned an NPC that would serve some use to the plot and at the end of the campaign but I started noticing that, if he dies or the party screws with him someway, then the plot would have to be re-written at the last moment.

The wizard of the party made a pact with a demon, which granted him power but made him cursed, after some days, his body will then be taken by the demon and the wizard will die. I planned to make this NPC a previous user of the curse but he managed to escape the death using a spell that makes them switch bodies.

If the party manages to let the NPC alive at some point, he would teach the spell to the wizard and then he will live, if he dies then the wizard is doomed. After something, I felt that this is not right, letting the plot and the live of a PC be controlled by just one single NPC feels like the choices of the players doesnt matter, what should I do?

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but plotwise, my mind just made somersaults of joy. If those two happened to have been cursed by the SAME demon... the very same one, that now undoubtedly really dislikes your NPC... Sorry, I am aware you have a plotline written out, but this is the kind of thing I just weirdly love!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I don't see a problem

You say that your problem is that the plot and the life of the wizard depends solely on the NPC, but there are many points, past and present, where the wizard exercised or can exercise his agency:

- He made the pact with the demon in the first place
- He can learn the spell from the NPC when or if he wants to
- He can go out of his way to protect the NPC
- Alternatively, he can get the NPC killed and he's stuck
- He can learn the spell from somewhere/someone else
- He can piss off the NPC and never learn the spell from him
- etc. etc.

As you can see, the wizard's fate rests in his own hands at many junctures. As the DM, you can control the wizard's access to methods to deal with his pact.

As for your plot, if this NPC dies, the PCs can still get the information or guidance another way. Concerns about railroading aside, there is always an alternative to seemingly critical NPCs. For example, in Harry Potter, Dumbledore got killed, but the main characters were still able to learn and get what they needed from him.

Finally, I don't see a problem on another level--the wizard made a classic Faustian bargain, and has to deal with it. If you let your players consistently get away with bad decisions, the choices won't matter because there aren't really any consequences. While this can be a fun playstyle, it's something worth considering for your game.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce him after a tough fight when the players are exhausted and without resources, they will think twice before messing with someone else when they are alredy pretty beaten up, wich gives you some precious moments that he can talk and show that he is a friend.

He doesn't need to save them Deus ex Machina style, just give him a chance to show that he is friendly and worth their time.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to let the players discover the plot.**

Mystery and suspense should be used in moderation. If the players do not know what is happening to or aroud them, they will feel helpless and frustrated. The truths and events you have planned may be logical and thus may *seem* fair to you, but the players have no agency over them. This can be done in some darker games, but is generally not expected of the more "heroic" advetures D&D is geared for.

Plan the events so that the PC-s have time and the means to discover what is going on. Also do not forget to let them know *what* needs discovering. In your example, the wizards needs to somehow learn (with no action on his part, as he couldn't initiate it) about the curse. He may have out of body experiences, nightmares of the Abyss or similar, and I also recommend you tell him something more explicit, like: "You feel your soul being pulled away as you draw on the demonic energies." when he uses his powers. Do not be afraid to just straight up tell them this stuff, as this is only so that they suspect or know that something is up. If they know about the possibilities and dangers involved, they can make an informed decision about what to do.

Give them multiple ways to discover the truth. Expecting them to work out the single solution you came up with is unadvised. You should read about the [three clue rule](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/1118/roleplaying-games/three-clue-rule) regarding this.

The last part is to give them power to act. In some situations this may be inherent in the system, in others they may need an item or help from an NPC. The idea of multiple ways should be observed here too. Do not feel a need to let just *any* idea the players come up with succeed, but plan multiple options for this too. If something like the life of a PC depends on it, you may be a litle flexible about it too.

If you and the players agree *before the campaign starts* to play a more grimdark game, you can forego some or most of this, but beware that the feeling of helplessness will remain. You should be clear about the style and feel you are going for ahead of time.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here, he asked how to introduce an NPC, not how to run his campaign.

Comment: @Manner I believe looking at it that way makes it an XY problem. Also the title/question is about the campaign, not the NPC.

Answer (score 1):

I am myself rather new to GMing, but I still like to try to give you some advice.

**Make the role and the purpose of your NPC replaceable**

I see and understand that this NPC you mention is very important to your campaign. That's ok, but remember that player will never to what you expect them to do. So it's always good to have have some sort of a back up for your plot. Specifically in this case this could mean having a back up for your villainous NPC.

I assume your NPC is a person of many resources and as such has goons, adversaries, and/or other allies. Any of those could already posses part of this NPCs knowledge or might even search for the same answers right now. Write down a few NPCs and their relation to your main NPC. It doesn't have to be detailed, just enough to give you some options later.

Now, if the party takes out your NPC, you will have others to fill his place, or rather his purpose in your campaine.

- This may be his favorite disciple whom he left an instruction and is ready to revenge his master.
- This may be his sworn enemy who has tricked him to confront the party and has now the possibility to access the secret knowledge while the party is busy celebrating their victory.
- ...

There is always a market for such valuable information and people who are willing to act accordingly.

The core of this idea is heavily inspired by [The Alexandrian](http://thealexandrian.net/) which has been mentioned in another answer already. Especially [CREATING MEMORABLE VILLAINS](http://thealexandrian.net/wordpress/36383/roleplaying-games/dont-prep-plots-you-will-rue-this-day-heroes-the-principles-of-rpg-villainy)  could be very helpful for your situation but there are also many other valuable articles to be found there.